# Will this snippet eat lot of php memory on apache?

Tags: php, memory-management

I want to add some 6000 lines of code in a php code for my website, running on LAMP.
It's on a shared hosting $6/month.

My question is will it eatup lot of php memory?

```
if($id==1)
{
sprintf($url,....);
}
else
if($id==2)
.....
```

and so on till `$id` equals `6000`

Comment: Completely apart from memory consumption, isn't there a better way to do that?! O_O

Comment: @deceze I think he insists on getting his money's worth.

Comment: @scrum-meister 0.01¢/if-statement seems overpriced to me `;)`

Comment: This code is in dire need of an industrial strength tumble DRYer.

Answer (score 3):

Getting to `$url` 6000 will take much longer than getting to `$url` 1. Not 6000 times longer, but much longer.

I'm not so sure about the wisdom of this design, but using [an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) would probably allow for much faster access time:

```
$urls = array(1 => "http://www.foo.bar/", 2 => "http://blubber.blorp/");
sprintf($urls[$id],...);
```

If all the URLs start with `http://`, then you could move that into your `sprintf()` call to save on memory. But 6000 strings times 100 bytes per (lets assume long URLs) is still just 600,000 bytes, and some overhead it's probably chewing less than one megabyte of memory total.

Comment: Other way is to store this data in an indexed file to save memory.

Comment: @user543087, true enough, a file that allocates 128 bytes per URL and is read using e.g. `pread(file, url, 128, $id * 128)` (mangling C and php :) would use very little memory, but might involve more trips to the disk. Using SQLite3 would probably be simpler, and doesn't put a length limitation on the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

It will eat up too much memory and CPU, even if "too much" is only a few kb; you can code it better than this.

Comment: Oh then what's the use of stack? How come CPU? If I were to place same info in DB then it'd eat much more memory and CPU!

Comment: possibly, but I wasn't thinking of using a DB. see sarnold's answer for one approach.

Comment: stack, not much. cpu has to iterate, worst case, over all 6000 cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it will "eat up" memory. The parser has to load 6000 if statements, urls, etc...

Since you're on LAMP, take advantage of the `M` by throwing the urls into a MySQL database and select the appropriate record based on the `$id`